# Inserting Text into a C# form

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, controls, innerhtml

I have a very large finance table, which will be repeated many times on a page, across many different pages.
I don't like the idea of just copying the table across pages. So I have created a control, which can be called into all the pages. I need to be able to INSERT the relevant figures through each financePage.aspx.cs backend.

a) I am struggling with editing the figures through each FinancePage.aspx.cs back end?

b) Or is there an issue with my work so far?

FinanceControl.aspx

```
<div class="span3  finance-boxes">                
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover finance-table">
    <tr><td>Title</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="fig" runat="server" ID="cell1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Title</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="fig" runat="server" ID="cell2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="#financeDetail36" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Finance Details</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

FinanceControl.aspx.cs

```
    public string Cell1Text
    {
        get
        {
            return cell1.InnerHtml;
            return cell2.InnerHtml;

        }
        set
        {
            cell1.InnerHtml = value;
            cell2.InnerHtml = value;
        }
    }
```

FinacePage.aspx
    Has the control included

FinancePage.asp.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        financeControl.Cell1Text.Cell1 = "FIGURE";
        financeControl.Cell1Text.Cell2 = "FIGURE";  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not want something as heavy duty as this, but often when a webforms developer is looking for a data-bound HTML Table this is the quickest long-term solution:

[GridView control built-in to .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx)

If you are not using webforms, then making a partial view in MVC with a data table model would be better and more easily composed with javascript and custom functionality, but it does not sound like that is what your infrastructure is compatible with.